# Is Vuex supported in tns preview?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

After including Vuex in my NativeScript-Vue mobile app, tns preview fails to resolve modules which depend on Vuex. The application works fine with tns run, tns build. The issue affects both IOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Preview app is built with specified set of plugins and works only with these plugins. The user is not able to add additional plugins to the preview app. Vuex is not included in the plugins from preview app and that is the reason why preview does not work.
I suspect `tns preview --bundle` command might be work so you can give it a try.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try with --bundle parameter. This is working perfectly! Thank you.